# Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary subsets of $\textbf{R}$. Then $\overline{X\cup Y} = \overline{X}\cup\overline{Y}$ (a question about closure)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary subsets of $\textbf{R}$. Then

(a) $X\subseteq\overline{X}$

(b) $\overline{X\cup Y} = \overline{X}\cup\overline{Y}$

(c) $\overline{X\cap Y}\subseteq\overline{X}\cap\overline{Y}$

**MY ATTEMPTS**

(a) The set $\overline{X}$ denotes the set of all adherent points of $X$. In particular, it contains the elements of $X$.

This is because, no matter which $\varepsilon > 0$ one chooses, if $x\in X$, there is an element of $X$ (namely, $x$ itself) such that $|x - x| = 0 < \varepsilon$. Thus $X\subseteq\overline{X}$.

(b) Let us prove the inclusion $(\subseteq)$ first.

If $a\in\overline{X\cup Y}$, no matter how small one chooses $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a number $b\in X\cup Y$ such that $|a - b| \leq \varepsilon$.

If $b\in X$, then $a\in\overline{X}$. If $b\in Y$, then $a\in\overline{Y}$. In both cases, $a\in\overline{X}\cup\overline{Y}$, and we are done.

Let us now prove the inclusion $(\supseteq)$

If $a\in\overline{X}\cup\overline{Y}$, then either $a\in\overline{X}$ or $a\in\overline{Y}$. Let us assume $a\in\overline{X}$.

Thus, no matter which $\varepsilon > 0$ one chooses, there is an element $b\in X\subseteq X\cup Y$ such that $|a-b|\leq\varepsilon$. Hence $a\in\overline{X\cup Y}$.

Analogously, let us suppose that $a\in\overline{Y}$. The same reasoning shows that $a\in\overline{X\cup Y}$. Therefore $\overline{X}\cup\overline{Y}\subseteq\overline{X\cup Y}$.

(c) Finally, let us prove the last assertion.

Let us suppose that $a\in\overline{X\cap Y}$. Then no matter which $\varepsilon > 0$ one chooses, there exists an element $b\in X\cap Y$ such that $|a - b|\leq\varepsilon$. Since $b\in X$ and $b\in Y$, this means that $a\in\overline{X}$ and $a\in\overline{Y}$, that is to say, $a\in\overline{X}\cap\overline{Y}$, just as desired.

I am little bit new to this. Could someone please verify if I am reasoning right?

Comment: For part (a), all you have to prove is that $x\in\overline{X}$ for any $x\in X$, which is by definition.

You $\subset$ proof for part (b) is wrong. In order to prove $a\in\overline{X}$, you have to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ you can find a real number $b_\epsilon\in X$ such that $|a-b_\epsilon|\leq\epsilon$. Your choice of $b$ for each $\epsilon$ could be either in $X$ or $Y$, which is not enough for you to conclude that $a\in\overline{X}$ (or $a\in\overline{Y}$).

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. Could you please provide a full answer so I can uptvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can prove (b) and (c) just by using (a)

both $X$ and $Y$ are a subsets of $X\cup Y$.
from that you have that  $\overline{X}$ ,  $\overline{Y} \subseteq \overline{X\cup Y}$. follows that their union is a subset of $\overline{X\cup Y}$ as well.
on the other hand, $X\cup Y  \subset \overline{X} \cup  \overline{Y} $
since $X \subset \overline{X}$ and $Y \subset \overline{Y}$.

use the same reasoning for c

Comment: You should add a bit details as well.